# Spectrum Analyzer for C#, similar to Winamp?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, fft

I want to have a spectrum analyzer as similar as possible to the one in Winamp (v5).
I tried http://wpfsvl.codeplex.com/ but the result is not nearly as good as in Winamp.
For example, if I put the chirp sound (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Linchirp.ogg) through it, Winamp seems to be much more accurate. With the C# example, the frequencies seem to "bleed" outside and so everything is much less pronounced. Also in general with any music, Winamp will pronounce everything much more and it's much more clear, in the C# one it's all very "blurry". E.g. when drums hit, in winamp this will be very obvious on the left part of the analyzer, while in the C# example it is hardly noticable.

Comment: Perhaps you can think to integrate something into your C# app...http://audio.software.informer.com/download-audio-spectrum-analyzer-delphi-component/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winamp is not accurate, it's tuned so it looks good.  For example, it DOESN'T have exact values, but does 'falloff' of the values so it look natural.

To emulate it, you'll have to go beyond mere FFT and eventual [binning](http://www.vlf.it/fft_beginners/fft_beginners.html) of the results.

Comment: And going beyond that means...?

Comment: What do you need more explanation about?

Comment: Try one of them: http://w3.westnet.gr/mp3/winamp/plugins/attached.htm and see how they behave...